# Connect Profile model to remote user (custom auth backend)

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am in the process of writing a custom authentication backend to authenticate against a RESTful API.

I don't know how I would connect a `Profile` model (that would contain information that isn't in the remote database) to those users in a way that is immune to changes in usernames, etc. For example, if I wanted to have a 'Bio' field for those users, then I would normally do this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

Is this possible with a custom API-based authentication backend? If so, what would I put in the `OneToOneField` that connects it to the remote users?

Would I just have to ensure the authentication backend updates a local database of users and then the Profile model would connect to that? That is how I was going to try this but I figured I would query the community on how this is done elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully this helps someone in the future. The way I solved this issue is in my authentication backend I queried the API and then found (or created) a local user object and updated the relevant properties of that object. It gets a little weird because the primary key of the local database is the id (and pk) of the remote user objects (to make lookups quick for `get_user()`) but I am authenticating with the username as the lookup key.

So, to summarize:

- Make backend query API and then sync the local db with the remote on that one user (local db exists merely to hold on to the remote data for user objects).
- To ensure your system works even when their remote username changes, ensure you use the remote id (that presumably wouldn't change ever) to sync the local db.
- Ensure that the primary key of the local user model is the primary key of the remote database to help yourself out with data integrity.

Also, in my example I have to download the entire accounts list and grep it for the right user. In my real-world example I am using an API that allows me to lookup by username. Downloading the entire accounts list is a crazily bad idea, I just do it here because my test API didn't support that.

`models.py`:

```
class RemoteUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, remote_id, remote_username=None, remote_first_name=None, remote_last_name=None, remote_email=None):
        if not remote_id:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a remote_id')
        user = self.model(
            remote_id=remote_id,
            remote_username=remote_username,
            remote_first_name=remote_first_name,
            remote_last_name=remote_last_name,
            remote_email=remote_email,
        )
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    def create_superuser(self, remote_id, remote_username=None, remote_first_name=None, remote_last_name=None, remote_email=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            remote_id=remote_id,
            remote_username=remote_username,
            remote_first_name=remote_first_name,
            remote_last_name=remote_last_name,
            remote_email=remote_email,
        )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class RemoteUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    remote_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    remote_username = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    remote_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    remote_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    remote_email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)     # testing login to admin interface
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=True) # testing login to admin interface
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = RemoteUserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'remote_username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
    def get_full_name(self):
        return str(self.remote_first_name + ' ' + self.remote_last_name).strip()
    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.remote_first_name
    def get_display_name(self):
        if (self.remote_first_name):
            return self.remote_first_name
        else:
            return self.remote_email
    def __str__(self):
        return self.remote_username
```

`backends.py`:

```
class RemoteAuthBackend(object):
    apikey = 'yourlongandsecureapikeygoeshere'
    target = 'https://remote.domain.com'
    list_call = '/admin/scaffolds/accounts/list.json'
    show_call = '/admin/scaffolds/accounts/show/'

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        username = username.strip()
        # run API call and find user by username
        request = urllib.request.Request(self.target + self.list_call + '?api_key=' + self.apikey)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
        resp_parsed = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
        # go through list of dicts and find the matching username
        match_user = None
        for user_record in resp_parsed:
            if user_record.get('login', None) == username:
                match_user = user_record
                print('testy')
                break
        if not match_user: return None
        # get password-crypted and salt
        crypted_password = match_user.get('crypted_password', None)
        salt = match_user.get('salt', None)
        # hash password and see if the digests match (base64 encoded sha1 digest)
        hash = b64encode(sha1((salt + password).encode('utf-8')).digest()).decode('utf-8')
        if hash == match_user.get('crypted_password'):
            # update user object that matches remote_id and return local user object
            try: local_user = models.RemoteUser.objects.get(pk=match_user['id'])
            except: local_user = None
            if not local_user:
                try: local_user = models.RemoteUser(remote_id=match_user['id'])
                except: return None   # This should never happen, ever
            local_user.remote_username = match_user.get('login', None)
            local_user.remote_first_name = match_user.get('first_name', None)
            local_user.remote_last_name = match_user.get('last_name', None)
            local_user.remote_email = match_user.get('email', None)
            try: local_user.save()
            except: return None
            return local_user
        else:
            # failed auth
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        # get user from remote and sync up local object properties based on remote_id
        request = urllib.request.Request(self.target + self.show_call + str(user_id) + '.json?api_key=' + self.apikey)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
        match_user = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
        if not match_user: return None
        try: local_user = models.RemoteUser.objects.get(pk=match_user['id'])
        except: local_user = None
        if not local_user:
            try: local_user = models.RemoteUser(remote_id=match_user['id'])
            except: return None   # This should never happen, ever
        local_user.remote_username = match_user.get('login', None)
        local_user.remote_first_name = match_user.get('first_name', None)
        local_user.remote_last_name = match_user.get('last_name', None)
        local_user.remote_email = match_user.get('email', None)
        try: local_user.save()
        except: return None
        return local_user
```

And you'll still have to modify `admin.py` like you would any time you use a custom user model.